# Why java.lang.VerifyError is thrown when reactor/core/Scannable is called?

Tags: java, project-reactor, spring-data-redis, redisson

I'm investigating the following java.lang.VerifyError:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: reactor/core/publisher/FluxCreate$BaseSink, method: scanUnsafe signature: (Lreactor/core/Scannable$Attr;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Illegal type in constant pool
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.createSink(FluxCreate.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe(FluxCreate.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4087) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribeOrReturn(FluxConcatMap.java:116) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromFluxOperator.subscribe(MonoFromFluxOperator.java:65) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4087) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4193) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3919) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:3.3.0.RELEASE]
```

I run following code with redisson-spring-data-21 3.12.0 library:

```
final Mono<Boolean> set = reactiveRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(jsessionId, sessionMap, Duration.ofMinutes(3));
set.doOnError(e -> LOGGER.error("Error")).subscribe();
```

The error occurs not consistently, after one deployment of application on Openshift all calls of subscribe() ended successful after another all calls ended with Verify Error exception.

I checked the dependencies and only one version of reactor-core library is used and included in the application jar.

Comment: Did you try to update reactor-core lib to the latest one?

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling the application against the same version of the libary you're using for deployment? That's usually the cause of a `VerifyError` in my experience, as oppose to conflicting library versions on the classpath itself.